How to find Broadcast Address
Suppose I have an IP address 192.168.1.0/26
What is the broadcast ID here? The solution is 192.168.1.63 but I don't know how it is calculated.

First lets convert the IP into binary
Given IP, 192.168.1.0/26
So the binary of the above IP = 11000000.10101000.00000001.00000000 ✔
Given subnet mask=26
So in the IP=11000000.10101000.00000001.00\000000(we have taken the 26 bits)
So now to determine Network address first we will take the remaining bits and turn them into 0's(Here its already 0)
So Network Address=192.168.1.0
And for Broadcast Address we will do the exact opposite of network address by converting the remaining bits into 1's(only the remaining 6 bits here)
So in binary it will look like= 11000000.10101000.00000001.00\111111
Giving us =     192.168.1.63
So in this way both network and broadcast address can be determined.
This video explanation will clear all the doubts:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hb2yTNT2rBU
